# SVN Merge - Completely "theirs full" - Branch to trunk

Tags: svn, svn-merge, svn-merge-reintegrate

I want to merge my branch to trunk and basically want to over-write all the code in branch to the trunk..While receiving conflicts I kept doing "theirs full" for all the conflict; but still at the end it shows so many conflicts.

All I want is over-write complete branch on my trunk. Surely a possible way is to branch out from my branch but then my trunk becomes useless !

Also, while doing svn merge can I give an option so that for all conflicts it takes a particular value ( in this case Full-theirs ) and I dont have to type it always for all the conflicts.

Answer (score 7):

Pass `--accept=theirs-full` to the `svn merge` command.

Answer (score 2):

If you want:

- Merge branch to trunk
- For any conflicts use full file from branch
- Do it automatically

you have to

- Have clean Working Copy of /trunk
- Merge in the root of WC your branch to it: `svn merge ^/branches/BRANCH`
- Use `accept` option in order to always prefer branch's file: add `--accept 'tf'` to merge and get final form `svn merge ^/branches/BRANCH --accept 'tf'`